# How to access the function variable outside of it in typescript..?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

This is the function where I'll get my picture values from firebase database and the problem is how to access `pictures` variable out of the function to an array so that I can loop through them and display it on my HTML.

```js
cato(){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
    var imgref = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        var pictures = snapshot.val();
    });
```

Comment: If you want to access the variable outside the function you also have to define it outside the function.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, there's an Angular library for Firebase: https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the callback pattern into promise based pattern so you can get the value from the callback like below:

```js
async cato(){
  const ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
  const pictures = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      resolve(snapshot.val());
    });
  });
  return pictures;
}
```

And you get the pictures from your component:

```js
...
async someMethod() {
    this.pictures = await cato();
}
```

Now you can use `pictures` in your html

---

**Note**: if your `cato` function is already a method of a component, you can set `pictures` property directly from your `cato` function.

```js
async cato() {
  const ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
  const snapshot = await ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added");
  // snapshot is available now
  this.pictures = snapshot.val();
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `cato` is already method of the component and now I want to access the `snapshot.val()` out of the `cato()` so that I can assisgn it to any array and loop through it in my html. **Note**: In my case `snapshot.val()` returns an array.

Comment: can you add your whole component? are you sure the cato is a method of a component?

Comment: It worked but In my case I am getting only one property from all objects ie. `picture` so now snapshot.val().picture returns an array and I am getting a single value?

Comment: actually you are only getting one document which is newly added to the collection. i am not sure about the firestore events well, but you have to use another event, not `child_added`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a "promised flavor" of the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method.

So you can do:

```
cato() {
     var pictures = null;
     var ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
     ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added")
         .then(function(snapshot) {
            pictures = snapshot.val();
         });
})
```

---

**Update following your comment:**

The `once()` method is asynchronous an returns a promise. It's only when this promise resolves that you can get the value of the `snapshot`. If you want to call the `cato()` function from another part of your code, you need to note that the `cato()` function will also be asynchronous.

The following would do the trick (note the `return`s in the `cato()` function):

```
cato() {
     var ref = firebase.database().ref("/images");
     return ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("nature").once("child_added")
         .then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val();
         });
})

// Call the asynchronous cato() function from another part of the code

cato().then(function(picturesArray) {
   yourArray = picturesArray;
})
```

Comment: But how to access `pictures` variable out the `cato()` function and assign it to an array?

Comment: I still didn't get you... Here's the whole component code..:https://codeshare.io/2BekWm